# How many records can I insert at once

Tags: t-sql, azure

I am using an Azure SQL database and I'm wondering if there is a limit on how many records I can insert at once. I have a case where I need to insert 7000+ records.

If there is a limit, anyone know a good way of inserting the records in batches?

```
foreach (var records in records)
{
    db.Records.Add(record);
}

db.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 1):

There is not straight answer on this question. Off course there is a limit on how many record you can insert. This depends on many things like 32/64bit / Memory / DB size / transaction size / add method to ef / number of records in one action / transactions locks on your db in a production situation etc. You can write some test that checks how big the chucks have to be like: [fastest-way-of-inserting-in-entity-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5940225/fastest-way-of-inserting-in-entity-framework). Or you can use AddRange: [Ef bulk insert](https://efbulkinsert.codeplex.com/).

```
db.AddRange(records);
db.SaveChanges();
```

You have to decide on if you need to insert the records in one transaction or you can use a number of transaction to keep your table locks smaller.